# Resizing frame of mapview

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have created a MapView in interface builder and when the user performs an action (presses a search button), I would like the frame of the mapview to change to accommodate a tableview that isn't previously visible before the user selects the search button. When the user selects the search button, the code below runs, which should reset the frame of the mapview to be just below my tableview. At runtime, the code appears to be working (the mapview resizes), but only for a second, and then the mapview snaps back to the size its set to in storyboard. Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening???

```
   self.mapView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y + self.tableView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - (self.tableView.frame.origin.y + self.tableView.frame.size.height));
```

Comment: I guess you should initialize the map when its needed, but you have added the map on the xib itself.

Comment: Strange behavior. Sounds like you have something else trying to tug the frame back towards the storyboard dimensions. You wouldn't have happen to have set any auto Layout constraints on mapView in the storyboard, would you? Also, in which method of your view controller did you put the line of code that you showed above?

Comment: This is probably due to auto layout. You can't set frames when using auto layout, you need to adjust the constraints instead.

Comment: Thanks, I never got it figured out, but I redesigned my view so I don't need the map to resize. Just added a segmented control to switch between map and table views.